# What is the redirect uri for spotify apps on android?

Tags: java, android, spotify

I want to make an Android app for Spotify but I need to set a redirect uri?

What Uri should I use?

I expected the redirect uri to be documented somewhere but didn't find anything useable on Google.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your Main activity you must compose a redirect uri like:

```
private Uri getRedirectUri() {
    return new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("protocol")
            .authority("appname")
            .build();
}
```

And, in the Dashboard user this url like:

```
protocol://appname
```

(both can be anything)